# Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration by parts

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $F$ be a probability distribution function on $\mathbb{R}$ whose support is contained in $[0,1]$. Is the following integration by parts hold for arbitrary such $F$: $$\int_{[0,a]}x \mathrm{d}F(x)= aF(a)-\int_0^aF(x)\mathrm{d}x?$$

Can anyone give me some classic references on the integration by parts for Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration? Thank you!

Comment: From my classical analysis class, $F$ should be of bounded variation for the Stieltjes integral for this to hold (I think). See Carothers' text _Real Analysis_ or even Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ for more info.